# Show dialogs from JUCE library

Tags: metal, juce

I want to develop an iOS/MacOS app which would use Metal for rendering. This is not supported as a “main window” by JUCE (yet). The reason I was to use JUCE is because it unifies acquiring access to audio interfaces, which is quite different between iOS and MacOS (and also has a GUI component for configuring the audio source, which AudioKit doesn’t have, which is why I don’t want to use it).

I’m struggling to generate a project in JUCE that would have Metal-backed view as a main component. So I’m thinking to instead make a library using JUCE, and then make two native apps for iOS and MacOS which would both use that library. The library would be used to show the dialogs for configuring the audio input (and other parameters that I have, through custom components).

The question: is it possible to make a JUCE library which would be capable if showing dialogs (on both iOS and MacOS) to configure my app, and then use this library from the native iOS and MacOS apps that would have a Metal-backed main view?

Thanks in advance!